# Why Minikube has different kernel version in its pods/containers than host OS?

Tags: kubernetes, linux, minikube

I am running Minikube on a Linux kernel 6.1.
I added a uname -r command in an image to check which kernel version the container "sees".
And its 5.10.57.

I expected the version to be 6.1 as well. Why is it different?

Minikube is using the kvm2 driver.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that Minikube uses an ISO to boot under a hypervisor and thus needs a kernel. I thought Minikube itself runs on the host OS.
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/contrib/building/iso/
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/10501